# How to convert an IPv4 address to the ASN (Autonomous System Number) on the command line?

Tags: networking, routing

Given an IPv4 address, how can I tell which ASN (Autonomous System Number) is hosting that address using command line tools only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find out who is **currently** announcing an address, you would have to either look at the routing table of a BGP-connected router (e.g. public ones at routeservers.org), or query an online database which periodically collects the announcements.

A commonly used service is the [Cymru IP-to-ASN mapping](https://www.team-cymru.com/IP-ASN-mapping.html) database, accessible through various protocols such as DNS (for automated queries), HTTP or WHOIS (for manual queries only):

```
$ dig +short google.com
172.217.x.y

$ dig +short -t TXT y.x.217.172.origin.asn.cymru.com
"15169 | 172.217.0.0/16 | US | arin | 2012-04-16"

$ whois -h whois.cymru.com 172.217.x.y
AS      | IP               | AS Name
15169   | 172.217.x.y      | GOOGLE, US
```

Another service is [RIPE RISwhois](https://www.ripe.net/analyse/archived-projects/ris-tools-web-interfaces/riswhois) (not the same thing as regular RIPE WHOIS DB):

```
$ whois -h riswhois.ripe.net 172.217.x.y
...
route:        172.217.0.0/16
origin:       AS15169
descr:        GOOGLE, US
lastupd-frst: 2019-10-31 10:45Z  198.32.243.219@rrc16
lastupd-last: 2020-03-05 23:53Z  80.81.192.244@rrc12
...
```

(Note that AS location does not always correspond with the device's physical location; it could be in a different country. In this example, the address range is in a different *continent* entirely.)

Beware that in certain situations, there could be multiple AS announcing the same prefix, and which one is visible could depend on your (or the database's) location. Try querying the AS number of `192.88.99.1`!

It could even be that the address is announced by some AS which *isn't* supposed to announce it (BGP hijacking). To find out who is **expected to** announce the address, query a routing database such as RADb or the RIPE WHOIS server.

```
$ whois -T route -h whois.ra.net 172.217.x.y
route:      172.217.169.0/24
descr:      Google
origin:     AS15169
...
```

Comment: Succeded with `host -t TXT <IP reversed>.origin.asn.cymru.com`.

Interesting results from `whois -T route -h whois.ra.net 192.88.99.1`. Thank you for the quick response.

Answer (score 0):

Another database you can use to determine this is [IP Guide](https://ip.guide), which is updated every 8 hours. As an example, you could use `curl` to determine the ASN announcing 8.8.8.8 with:

```
$ curl -sL https://ip.guide/8.8.8.8 | jq .network.autonomous_system.asn
15169
```

(note that `jq` is not necessary, but can pull a specific portion of the JSON out of the response)